# By what process was this question reopened?

Tags: discussion, moderation, closed-questions, specific-question

It took a while to gather the 5 close votes to close this question:

[What rights do students in the U.S. have re gender pronouns?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/77827/10643)

My comment giving my reason to vote to close it was voted up 15 times

The meta post asking if such questions should be closed has a positive vote count:

[Should legal questions be closed as too narrow?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3497/10643)

Yet the question reopened less than an hour ago in an eye blink. How?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly. The [edit history](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/77827/revisions) shows who voted to reopen. What do you mean by "how"?

Comment: Also note that per the [post timeline](http://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/77827/timeline/), it was closed about 10 hours after it was asked, and then reopened about 29 hours after it was closed. I wouldn't say that is an "eye blink".

Comment: "The meta post asking if such questions should be closed has a positive vote count:" You seem to infer from this community support for closing. But this seems a **huge** stretch. Users do not vote like this. There are two answers. The one in favor of the post is at +10 the one against at -1. The meta question was asked by somebody in favor of having the question open. An upvote on the question if anything could be seen as support for this. Also see the comment there.

Comment: The process is called community moderation, and it obviously works as it should.

Comment: For the record, I am not sure about  the merits of the question you asked about, but as regards the process of open/close I see not problem at all.

Comment: This is the second question against which you have a strong opinion that gets closed at first but then reopened, and for which you have opened a discussion on meta. Probably, you should accept the fact that a part of this community is willing to read and answer a broader range of questions.

Comment: @ff524 that's the answer to my question I didn't know the reopen votes were listed there.

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dilaton very helpful. If you have more details as to in which time frame which events happened, please post an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The [edit history](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/77827/revisions) shows who voted to reopen.

Also note that per the [post timeline](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/77827/timeline/), it was closed about 10 hours after it was asked, and then reopened about 29 hours after it was closed.  (You can click "toggle format" at the top of the post timeline page to see the exact timestamp of each event.)

Comment: The timeline is hard to parse for me. It shows it got closed, then there were 3 reviews to leave closed on one to reopen and then all 5 reopen votes show up as a single event.

Comment: @CapeCode The question got one reopen vote in the review queue; the other four came from people who voted directly on the post, both before and after it went through the review queue.

Comment: Interesting. The timeline does not show at wich time each of the close and reopen votes were casted. It's the speed at which the 5 reopen votes were gathered that surprised me.

Comment: @CapeCode 29 hours is speedy to you? Wow :)

Comment: Is that from the first reopen vote to the last, or since it was closed?

Comment: @CapeCode 29 hours from the time it was closed to the time it was reopened. There's about 2 hours between the time it was closed and the time of the first reopen vote.

Comment: @CapeCode votes often come in bunches because of the review queue. When someone votes to open/close a question high rep users get a review notiifcation.

Comment: @StrongBad that was also the kind of information I was missing. I saw the post got from 0 or 1 reopen votes to reopened without a phase in between.